# MongoDB - Update to flatten inner array of arrays for each document

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection of documents, in which an inner property is an array of objects, but these were stored by mistake grouped by in inner arrays, like the following instance, specifically the "recs" property:

```
{
  "_id": ObjectId("5d52e851b412ca0001f10038"),
  "idIntegracaoContabil": NumberLong(6583),
  "protocol": "489dsad3-b075-4bc2-8631-9c01cc778e75",
  "content": {
    "idInteg": "1f2bd0d3b48978c286319c01cc778e75",
    "recs": [
      [
        {
          "desc": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet",
          "type": "TYPE1"
        },
        {
          "desc": "Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error",
          "type": "TYPE2"
        }
      ],
      [
        {
          "desc": "Et harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio",
          "type": "TYPE3"
        }
      ]
    ]
  },
  "createdBy": "admin"
}
```

Now I need to update all elements of this collection, flattening those arrays in a single array of the desc/type objects. I have looked up that I should use aggregate functions, like $unwind, to get this result, but I can't figure out how to do it in an update.

Answer (score 0):

If your MongoDB version is >= 3.4, I believe the best way to do it is using the operator [$reduce](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/reduce/) to flatten the array.

You could do:

```
db.your_collection.aggregate(
  [
    {
      $project: {
        "_id": 1,
        "idIntegracaoContabil": 1,
        "protocol": 1,
        "content.idInteg": 1,
        "content.recs": {
            $reduce: {
                input: '$content.recs',
                initialValue: [],
                in: {$concatArrays: ['$$value', '$$this']}
            }
        },
        "createdBy": 1,  
      }
    },
    {$out: "your_collection"}

  ]
)
```

In this case, as you can see, you will need to add all the fields to the projection, in order to save an updated version of the document using [$out](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/out/)

If you don't care about using aggregation or not, you can do the job iterating over a `find()` cursor:

```
db.your_collection.find({}).forEach(
    function(doc) {    
        doc.content.recs = doc.content.recs.reduce((a, b) => a.concat(b), []);
        db.your_collection.save(doc);
    }
)
```

Although this approach is less performant than the aggregation, it comes in handy sometimes. I prefer using this approach when using Mongo Shell, for example, as its syntax is easier to remember and allows us to deal only with the fields we need to change. In my aggregation example, if you forget to add a field to the projection, the document will be saved without that field.